# How to display OpenWeatherMap icons in weather application?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, api

I'm trying to display weather icons from OpenWeatherMap in my weather application using JavaScript.

I've tried using jQuery and other solutions I've seen online. I've also tried specifying this link ("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/") using the "src" attribute, but the link doesn't work and the image is broken as a result.

How do I successfully add weather icons to my application?

Here is some minimal code used to formulate this problem. I hope this helps.

HTML:

```
<div class="weather">
  <div id="date"></div>
  <div id="cityName"></div>
  <img src="" id="icon">
  <div id="temp"></div>
  <div id="description"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = n;

function getWeather( cityID ) {
  var key = '535f8a50b4bc24608c72fcde2aecb52b';
  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=' + cityID+ '&appid=' + key)  
  .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) 
  .then(function(data) {
    drawWeather(data);
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // catch any errors
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  getWeather( 6167865 );
}

function drawWeather( d ) {
  var celcius = Math.round(parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15);
  var fahrenheit = Math.round(((parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15)*1.8)+32); 

  document.getElementById('cityName').innerHTML = d.name;
  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = d.weather[0].description;
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + '&deg;';
  document.getElementById('icon').src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+obj.weather[0].icon+".png";
 }
```

Comment: Try using http://weatherdbi.herokuapp.com/. Though it is very new, it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `d.weather[0].icon` with existing one when you set url in image src property.

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = n;

function getWeather( cityID ) {
  var key = '535f8a50b4bc24608c72fcde2aecb52b';
  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=' + cityID+ '&appid=' + key)  
  .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) 
  .then(function(data) {
    drawWeather(data);
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // catch any errors
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  getWeather( 6167865 );
}

function drawWeather( d ) {
  var celcius = Math.round(parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15);
  var fahrenheit = Math.round(((parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15)*1.8)+32); 

  document.getElementById('cityName').innerHTML = d.name;
  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = d.weather[0].description;
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + '&deg;';
  document.getElementById('icon').src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${d.weather[0].icon}.png`;
 }
```

```html
<div class="weather">
  <div id="date"></div>
  <div id="cityName"></div>
  <img src="" id="icon">
  <div id="temp"></div>
  <div id="description"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @Adrian

Answer (score 1):

The open weather API documentation given the url to access icons. To display weather icon on webpage use the following method:

```
var iconCode = data.weather[0].icon; 
console.log(iconCode);
out_icon.innerHTML="<img 
src=http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+iconCode+"@2x.png>";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the document for using weather icons: https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions

In your case, you can change

```
document.getElementById('icon').src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+obj.weather[0].icon+".png";
```

to be

```
document.getElementById('icon').src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+ data.weather[0].icon +"@2x.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

`document.getElementById('icon').src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+obj.weather[0].icon+".png";`

with

`document.getElementById('icon').src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+d.weather[0].icon+".png";`

Comment: Appreciate the help, my friend!